# Download in Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I need an HTML code or JavaScript code to download a media file (mp3, mp4) that is supported by Safari browser.
I tried to use HTML5 download attribute it only works on chrome and IE.

Comment: I don't get what your asking? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a link?

```
  <a href="http://sourcetoyourfile.com/folder/file.mp4" target="_blank">Download Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<form method="get" action="file.doc">
<button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

`